# set() not removing duplicates

Tags: python, regex, list, python-3.x, set

I'm trying to find unique instances of IP addresses in a file using regex. I find them fine and try to append them to a list and later try to use `set()` on my list to remove duplicates. I'm finding each item okay and there are duplicates but I can't get the list to simplify. The output of printing my set is the same as printing ips as a list, nothing is removed.

```
ips = [] # make a list
count = 0
count1 = 0
for line in f: #loop through file line by line
    match = re.search("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", line) #find IPs
    if match: #if there's a match append and keep track of the total number of Ips
        ips.append(match) #append to list
        count = count + 1
ipset = set(ips)
print(ipset, count)
```

This string `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 13), match='137.43.92.119'>` shows up 60+ times in the output before and after trying to `set()` the list

Comment: the syntax is correct..maybe you need to check `ips`

Comment: You're making a set of *match objects*.

Comment: @rock321987 the list is printing the exact same output as I can tell if I print both

Comment: @user2357112 is there a way to just add the actual matched string to the list? Would that change anything?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are not storing the matched strings. You are storing the [*`re.Match` objects*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects). These don't compare equal even if they matched the same text, so they are all seen as unique by a `set` object:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = '137.43.92.119\n'
>>> match1 = re.search("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", line)
>>> match1
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 13), match='137.43.92.119'>
>>> match2 = re.search("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", line)
>>> match2
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 13), match='137.43.92.119'>
>>> match1 == match2
False
```

Extract the matched text instead:

```
ips.append(match.group()) #append to list
```

[`matchobj.group()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group) without arguments returns the part of the string that was matched (group 0):

```
>>> match1.group()
'137.43.92.119'
>>> match1.group() == match2.group()
True
```